# splitViewController not working correctly in iOS 6

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, ios6

i have a problem in ios 6. It shows splitviewcontroller only on portrait mode.

So, i got this warning message:

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

I had changed
`window addSubview:splitViewController.view`;

to

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController ;
```

It now shows landscape mode but not full screen.

Could somebody direct me or help to resolve problem?

Answer (score 0):

[window setRootViewController:splitViewController];

and see solution on the https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/MGSplitViewController/commit/a63c963ac56f597b90b7ef9fbe06f5082d8da851

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this problem [Changing DetailViewController on btn click in RootViewController fails on iOS6 in iPad Portrait Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997051/changing-detailviewcontroller-on-btn-click-in-rootviewcontroller-fails-on-ios6) as well? It is related to your original questions.